# Why all bolt acked but the spout fail?

Tags: apache-storm

I'm using JmsSpout and BaseBasicBolt.
All bolts acked, but a lot(about half) of spout fail.
What's the possible reason?
or how can I log why the message fail? the JmsSpout just print which message fail, without error info.

Comment: after several restarts, it become well magically, still can't find why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not actively `fail()` tuples in bolts, the only reason for failing tuples is a **timeout**. The default timeout in Storm is 30 seconds (you can configure it via `TOPOLOGY_MESSAGE_TIMEOUT_SECS`). If a tuples get emitted, Storm wait for the timeout duration to receive an ack. If not ack is received within this duration, Strom fails the tuple.

Increasing the timeout can fix the problem (you should set the timeout to a larger value than your expected processing latency).

If your expected processing latency is already lower then the timeout value, it indicates that you have a bottleneck in you topology. Thus, one (or multiple) operators cannot process incoming tuples fast enough. Therefore, incoming tuples get buffered in input queues increasing there latency as the queue is growing over time. You need to increase the parallelism for those bottleneck operators to resolve the issue.